# How to simplify an expression with absolute and log functions?

Tags: absolute-value

I'm confused with regard to simplifying this expression:

$$
|x| - |x-A| > \ln(\Gamma)
$$

I was thinking of taking square on both ends, and that's basically where I got confused. Should I square the whole left side of the expression, i.e. $(|x| - |x-A|)^2$ or can I get away with just squaring them individually?

If I decide to square them individually, I get the following:

$$
 2Ax - A^2 > (\ln(\Gamma))^2
$$

Finally:

$$
x > (\ln(\Gamma)^2 + A^2)/2A
$$

Am I doing this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't square terms being added together individually. For instance, this is true:
$$1+1=2,$$
but this is not:
$$1^2+1^2=2^2.$$

Depending on what you want, you could make a number of simplifications. One would be to multiply by $|x|+|x-A|$, creating a difference of squares on the left to get:
$$x^2-(x-A)^2 > \ln(\Gamma)(|x|+|x-A|).$$

If you want to get rid of every absolute value, then you'll have to square multiple times. For instance, **assuming both sides are positive**, you can square the whole expression to get
$$x^2+(x-A)^2 -|x(x-A)|>\ln(\Gamma)^2$$
And then rearrange to get
$$x^2+(x-A)^2-\ln(\Gamma)^2>|x(x-A)|$$
and then square again (since both sides *are* positive now, assuming their were initially)
$$(x^2+(x-A)^2-\ln(\Gamma)^2)^2>x^2(x-A)^2$$
which has no absolute values.

---

However, algebraic manipulations are not a particularly good way to attack this sort of problem. If we split into cases, then we can get rid of the absolute values entirely; for instance, if we assume $A$ is positive (it's easy to work out the necessary modifications if it negative) we split into cases:

- Case 1: $x\leq 0$. Then $x-A<0$ so $|x|=-x$ and $|x-A|=-x+A$. Thus the inequality is $-A > \ln(\Gamma)$ in this case.
- Case 2: $0\leq x \leq A$. Then $|x|=x$ and $|x-A|=-x+A$. The inequality is $2x - A > \ln(\Gamma)$ in this case.
- Case 3: $A \leq x$. Then $|x|=x$ and $|x-A|=x-A$. The inequality is $A>\ln(\Gamma)$ in this case.

We can quickly work out constraints on $x$ assuming $A$ is positive - in particular, if $-A>\ln(\Gamma)$, then all $x$ satisfy the inequality. If $A\leq \ln(\Gamma)$, then no $x$ satisfy the inequality. If $-A\leq \ln(\Gamma)<A$, then any $x$ greater than $\frac{\ln(\Gamma)+A}2$ satisfies the inequality.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. What I want to do is get an expression in the following form: either x > [expression] or x < [expression]

Comment: It might well be possible that you have $x <[\mbox{expression}]$ when $A \in \mbox { (some set)}$ and $x> [\mbox{another expression}]$ when $A \in \mbox{ (another set)}$. But I'm sure you can make it.

Comment: @Ali Ah, well then algebraic manipulations aren't a good way to do that. If you split into the cases where $|z|=z$ and $|z|=-z$ for each absolute value in the expression, you'll end up with linear equations, as you can simply remove the absolute value and change the sign or not as necessary.

Comment: @Meelo Ok, I'll try it that way then. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you have
$$a<b$$
you can not always just square both sides. You must have that both sides are positive which does not seem to be your case.

But you might try the following: You have $$|x| - |x-A| \leq |A|$$
So
$$ |A| \geq \ln (\Gamma).$$

I don't know if this is good enough for your purposes.